# How to point image-path scss helper to relative URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

My app's production instance is running on relative URL: `http://server/app_domain/`

`image-path` scss helper is pointing to `/assets/image1234.png` which resolves into

`http://server/assets/image1234.png`

instead of

`http://server/app_domain/assets/image1234.png`

Is there any configuration to setup the root url for the application? I would expect the image-path to generate `../assets/image1234.png` or `/app_domain/assets/image1234.png`

I am using JRuby/warbler/JBoss for prod/uat deployment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/environments/production.rb` you can set the asset host that is being used in all asset helpers.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://server/app_domain/"
```

This will give you absolute urls but the way you need it.